# Where can I find a really good guide for BIND9?

Tags: linux, bind, dns-server

Hey there, I have installed a BIND9 server on my Linux server. But I was struggling to get it working as I searched for various websites to explain the different settings for BIND.

Does anyone know where I can find a good guide to configuring and securing BIND9? I am running on Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit though I may changed OSes down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice [website](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/) about bind. It is actually a book.

Comment: looks good, I will have to take some time to read it over but I think it will work.

Answer (score 4):

- [DNS and BIND](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100575) by O'Reilly
- [BIND9 Administrator's Reference Manual ("ARM")](http://www.isc.org/files/arm97.pdf)

Comment: Very nice, I feel better when I have manual for the software I use. On a side note is there one of those for DHCPd?

Comment: I don't think so.  Just the softcopy documentation it comes with, plus http://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/documentation